# jQuery select all - Button must get enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this script right now

```
var checkboxes = $(".msgID"), submitButt = $(".DeleteAll");
    checkboxes.click(function() {
      submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    });
```

To check if there is any checkbox checked or not.. If there is one checked enable the delete all button..

It works just as i want, but i have a "MarkAll" button to, and if i click this i check all the boxes but i can't change the statement of the "DeleteAll" button, any clue how i can do this?

Comment: Use `change` event instead of `click`, also use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the MarkAll button is part of the selection that you get by querying:

```
var checkboxes = $(".msgID")
```

The change event that checks the state of the `submitButt` only triggers for this selection. Also I would definitely change the name of that variable, that is not a submitButt, that is a delete all.

Another suggestion for the future is to name classes as lowercase separated by a dash, like `delete-all`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much for the "puff" in the right direction! :)